Does a deity protect atman?
I've heard of bhakti yoga, meditation, etc., as a means of liberation or moksha, but does any scripture profess a deity to be the protector of atman?

Soul need no protection in bhagwad Gita
is is said → Only the material body is perishable; the embodied soul within is indestructible, immeasurable, and eternal. Therefore, fight, O descendent of Bharat.
